# Drop decimals and add commas Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want a column in my Dataframe to have no decimals but have commas.  It's for a bar chart.  Every time I add the commas I get the decimals.  Even if I convert the column to integers first.  Here is the DataFrame and what I tried that is not working!

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/ngpsu22/indigenous-peoples-day/raw/main/native_medians_means')

summary.med_resources_per_person.astype(int)
summary["med_resources_per_person"] = (summary["med_resources_per_person"].apply(lambda x : " 
                                       {:,}".format(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually changing the dtype to int inside of the dataframe. You'll need to assign it back to the column:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/ngpsu22/indigenous-peoples-day/raw/main/native_medians_means')

df["med_resources_per_person"] = df["med_resources_per_person"].astype(int)
df["med_resources_per_person"].apply(lambda x : "{:,}".format(x))
```

Or a little bit more concise:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/ngpsu22/indigenous-peoples-day/raw/main/native_medians_means')

df["med_resources_per_person"] = df["med_resources_per_person"].astype(int).apply("{:,}".format)
```